# Grub2 network-based boot choice

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I run a computer-science lab at a university with about 50 workstations that dual boot Debian and Windows XP. Obviously the grub default is Windows but there are times where it would be extra useful if we could boot the machines straight to Linux, like when there is a Linux related class or we want to access the Linux partition when we boot them remotely.

So what I'm basically asking is

1. Does GRUB have basic script capabilities like "if var=true boot 1 else boot 2"?
2. Is GRUB network-aware?

Comment: [Maybe this DeveloperWorks article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-osswitch/) can be helpful, describing how a "bootcontrol" setup that enables you to programmatically "Reboot to Linux" via GRUB's `configfile` directive and a config file on a shared partition... Another angle might be [PXE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment)-booting [GRUB](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Network.html)

Comment: [grub-choose-default](http://ds.mcbf.net/wiki/GrubChooseDefault) looks promising, but I've never used it. Please try it, and report back if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a PXE server which serves [PXELINUX](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/PXELINUX) with a configuration which [chain loads](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/Comboot/chain.c32) a partition boot sector on the local disk. When you want to use Linux you would modify the PXELINUX configuration on the server and reboot the machines. The BIOS on the machines should be set to PXE boot first, and GRUB should be installed to the partition (not the MBR).

Comment: ... or you can PXE boot grub directly. You don't need to use pxelinux.